# JAVA to Python MD5 hashlib

Tags: python, java, md5, hashlib

I am trying to convert java code into python for doing some encryption using md5. Can you please help me to solve this.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    String result = "";
    JSONObject o1 = new JSONObject();
    o1.put("stationId","1298491919448667556");
    String body = o1.toJSONString();
    System.out.println(body);
    try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md.update(body.getBytes());
        byte[] b = md.digest();
        result = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(b);
        System.out.println("ContentMD5:"+result);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Output: 5pxCd9dmyPR/V2jerFJdXQ==

Python code sample:

```
import json
import base64, hashlib

body_content = {}
body_content["stationId"] = "1298491919448667556"
body = json.dumps(body_content, sort_keys=True).encode()

hash = hashlib.md5()
hash.update(body)
content_md5 = base64.b64encode(hash.digest()).decode()

print("content-md5",content_md5)
```

Output: nc9o/UcyLURh7uEbz6A+8w==

Please help me to get same output as java.

Comment: Do `JSONObject::toJSONString` and `json.dumps` return the EXACT same string, including whitespaces?

Comment: when i am printing JSONOBJECT.toJSONString   it gives {"stationId":"1298491919448667556"}          json.dumps gives   b'{"stationId": "1298491919448667556"}'

Comment: And here is the difference that makes up the different hashes. Space after colon.

Comment: Thanks.  b'{"stationId":"1298491919448667556"}' this solves the issue.